# What are the elements of this apartment map?

Tags: doors

I was wondering what the elements from this map indicated with an arrow are?

[image: Map]

The apartment has no kitchen, and it is supposed to be unfurnished, but some elements are there (like a fridge?).

Comment: A box of lightning, an empty box, a robot hiding in a box, and a door.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, They are proposed appliances. not the same symbols we use here in the USA however. the arrow at the bottom is an egress window.